Point of Inflection of a Quintic $ x^5 $
$ y = x^{5}-5x^{4}+15x+4 $
Finding the Inflection Point requires the solutions $ f''(x) = 0$
$f''(x)=20x^3-60x^2 $
as $ f''(x)=0 $
$ 20x^2 (x - 3)=0$
$ x=3 $ and $ x=0 $
However only x=3 is a valid solution.I'm unsure why 0 is not a solution if the equation produces it as one.Am I missing a rule etc?

Also check whether $f''(x)$ changes sign at $x=0$.

An inflection point changes $f''$ from a positive value (concave upward) to a negative value (concave downward) or vice versa. Points near $0$($0^{+}$ or $0^{-}$) does not change the sign.

An inflection point occurs when there is a change in sign around $f''(a)$. In your case, there is not a change in sign around $f''(0)$; in particular, the second derivative in a sufficiently small neighborhood around $x=0$ is always non-positive.
In a case such as yours, you might instead refer to what happens at $x=0$ as an undulation point as per the inflection point wikipage.

Thanks, x=0
is a double root, there is no change of sign. It is a flat point, not an inflexion. –
Yves Daoust. Is this the same concept?
